install.packages() all of a sudden gives > Error: package 'foo' is not available for everything I try
I have for no known reason started to get Error: package 'foo' is not available, no matter what I try to install.
I have found a workaround that if I use install.packages("foo", method = "wininet"), it works perfectly fine. But I can't for the life of me understand why this has happened...
Anyone experienced the same problem and got a solution?
Edit: problem is now solved, just uncheck "automatic identification of settings" under proxy settings.
R version 4.4.1
Thx / Jonas

Follow this check list: https://deanattali.com/blog/packageunavailable/

Are you in windows? Are you under a vpn? More context needed.

libcurl is probably not detecting your proxy configuration: https://forum.posit.co/t/install-packages-only-works-with-wininet-how-set-default-download-file-method-to-wininet/172779/2

It's the same wether I'm home or at my office. At home I don't use any proxy. It has worked just recently, it might have occured after updating Rstudio and R to a newer version as  in the forum post at posit from @Axeman. Tried that but it didn't help:/

problem solved, thx all for pointing me in the right direction!
